# iterate over pyqt objects

Tags: python, oop, pyqt

### Problem :

I used Qt Designer and created 20 Graphics Views.

I want to iterate on them and change there background color inside the loop.

How i can do this?

#### Extra:

what i am trying to do:

I have 20 computers and i want to notify the user which terminals are not Used.
I have this date on files and every 2 min i will read it, go over the graphics Views and change their background color accordingly to their current status.

thanks pol

Answer (score 1):

```
    class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
            ...

        def my_method(self):

            for child in self.children():

                if isinstance(child, QtGui.QGraphicsView): 
                    ...
```